# CSS Button Value Styling

Tags: html, css, button, styling

If I have this line of code:

```
<input type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add" value="Add new"/>
```

How can I use CSS to style the buttons value? 
I need to add an image before it's value, therefore I'd need this line of code at the value output:

```
<span class="add">Add new</span>
```

I tried things like:

```
<input type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add" value="">
<span class="add">Add new</span></input>
```

haha, but this totally doesn't make any sense.

Anyone a good tip?

**EDIT**

Wow thanks for the great fast responses. Forgot to mention that I use a .CSS file of "sexybuttons", so I can't change the styling and need other approach.

```
<button type="submit">
```

Is what I was looking for. Thanks alot all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using the `button` tag instead of `input`.

```
<button type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add">
  <img src="path_to_image">
  <span class="add">Add new</span>
</button>
```

Or you could set a `background-image` for the button using CSS.

Comment: If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a background image using css and apply that to the button like this:

**css:**

```
input[type=button],input[type=submit],button{
    background:url(images/btn-verzend.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:91px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    border:none;
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**html:**

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Send" />
<input type="button" name="add" value="Send" />
<button>Send</button>
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add" value="Add new"/>
```

then add a css

```
.mybutton{
   // use css background attributes
   background:transaparent url(//image);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i hope you are looking this...........

[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/HObS2CEs)

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add" value=""/>
```

**CSS**

```
.mybutton {
background: url(http://coursesandevents.anjaschuetz.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/submit_button_large_red.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  width:248px;
  height:262px;
  border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<button type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add" value="">
  <span class="add">Add new</span>
</button>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HCLr/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add" value="Add new"/>

.mybutton{
background:url(image.jpg)no-repeat;
height:12px;
width:12px;
color:#fff;
border:none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add" value="Add New" />​
```

**CSS**

```
input{
    background:#58D3F7 url(http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/home.png) no-repeat left;
    background-size:20px;
    padding:10px 25px;
    text-align:center;
    border:none; border-radius:3px; cursor:pointer

}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ynr42/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
<span id="addSubmitButton" class="add" class="mybutton">Add new</span>
```

Then add this to the css:

```
.mybutton:before{
content:"url(image.jpg)";
}
```

or you can use jquery to do it without changing your original code as shown below:

```
$("#addSubmitButton").before("<img src='image.jpg' alt='image'/>");
```